# Adding CustomXMLParts in MS Word

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, xml-parsing

Using MS Word, I don't like the Table of Authorities hack to make a glossary, so I figured I'd whip out some VBA and use CustomXMLParts to make my own glossary.  Here's my sample XML:

```
Sub XMLGlossary()
    Dim gloss As String
    Dim xmlPart As CustomXMLPart
    
    If ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count > 4 Then
        killXMLGlossaryData
    End If
    
    gloss = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & _
      "<entries xmlns:g='gvkv.ca/word/xmlns/glossary'>" & _
        "<entry>" & _
          "<item>item1</item>" & _
          "<defn>defn1</defn>" & _
        "</entry>" & _
      "</entries>"
    
    ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Add gloss
    
    'It's in there.
    Debug.Print ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts(ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count).XML
    
    'Let's get it...
    Dim gnode As CustomXMLParts
    Set gnode = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("gvkv.ca/word/xmlns/glossary")
    Debug.Print TypeName(gnode) & ": " & gnode.Count
End Sub
```

and ... no dice.  The Immediate Window displays:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><entries xmlns:g="gvkv.ca/word/xmlns/glossary"><entry><item>item1</item><defn>defn1</defn></entry></entries>
CustomXMLParts: 0
```

So, my entry is not retrieved.  I've taken a look at [this](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/15176-customxmlparts-selectbynamespace.html), some answers here, and the MS docs but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I've also tried explicitly using the namespace `<g:entry> ...` but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing?

Also, why is Word removing the encoding  attribute in my XML declaration?

Comment: `CustomXMLParts.Add` takes an XML *fragment* not a complete document including the declaration.

Comment: Some useful info here: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/tinkering_with_CustomXMLParts.html

Comment: Switching to `<entries xmlns='gvkv.ca/word/xmlns/glossary'>` works for me.

Comment: (moved from my 'Answer' to this comment. "ThisDocument" and "ActiveDocument" are not necessarily the same thing.

 There are only 3 built-in CustomXMLParts. The code

     ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count > 4 

might need to say

    ThisDocument.CustomXMLParts.Count > 3 

but it depends on exactly what killXMLGlossaryData does. (You can remove non-builtin parts by testing for a Part's .Builtin property)

If you remove all CustomXMLPart objects from ThisDocument and ActiveDocument, and change all ThisDocument references to ActiveDocument references, it may work (it did here).

Comment: See also https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customXML_helpful_help.html.